# Bulk Image Copy with same filename and extension

Tags: vb.net, copy, filenames

When I load images using openfiledialog I need to store a backup copy of the images to the other folder using the same filename and with the same extension.So how do i do that as in the below mentioned code I am able to copy only one image and I have given random string for that image.But I don't need that.I want to copy with the same filename and with the same extension.And if I have the same filename it should overwrite it but not with a different name and extension.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
 If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True
        Dim r As New Random()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim strTemp As String = ""


        For i = 0 To 8
            strTemp = strTemp & Chr(CInt(Int((26 * r.NextDouble()) + 65)))
        Next

        Dim str As String
        For Each str In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            System.IO.File.Copy(str, Application.StartupPath + "\DownloadedImages\" & "strTemp.jpg", True)
        Next
    End If
```

And I achieved it but there is one problem I am able to copy one image can you say me how to do it for multiple images.And here is the code:

```
 Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
        Dim str As String
        str = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        MyExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(str)
        For i = 0 To OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Length - 1
            System.IO.File.Copy(OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(i), Application.StartupPath + "\DownloadedImages\" + strTemp & "." & MyExtension, True)
        Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim str As String
        For Each str In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
            Dim MyName As String
            Dim MyExtension As String

            MyName = fso.GetFileName(CStr(str))
            MyExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(MyName)
            System.IO.File.Copy(str, Application.StartupPath + "\Backup\" + MyName & "." & MyExtension, True)
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(str, CheckState.Checked)
            Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(str)
            Thumbcontrol1.BackgroundImage = Nothing
            CheckedListBox1.SelectedIndex = 0
        Next
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(str, Application.StartupPath + "\DownloadedImages\" & "strTemp.jpg", True)
```

Should read:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(str, Application.StartupPath + "\DownloadedImages\" & strTemp & ".jpg", True)
```

Comment: Yeh thanks for your reply but if I have many images with different extensions then how do i copy with same extension.

Comment: Yes I have worked it and modified and placed the so that it might help others.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class. It has methods for getting files names with or without extension as well getting the extension only.

Also, `strTemp` should not be in quotes as this will be the literal string `"strTemp"` not the value in the variable `strTemp`

Comment: no problem, feel free to upvote and/or mark as awnser if you think its appropriate :)